# Why isn't this triggering the default video player?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm using the following code in an application of mine, and it's always used to work with the default video player in Android 3.0 - 3.2. I haven't updated the OS, but for some reason the default video player no longer shows up as an option when you select which application you want to open the video file with.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filePath), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

I may have changed the `setDataAndType()` method from `Uri.fromFile(file)` to `Uri.parse(filepath)`, but would that be enough to make such a difference?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there video player installed on your device(on which you are running your app)?

Comment: Yes, I've got three video players installed - two of them show up, but the default OS video player doesn't. I'm running it on an Acer Iconia A500, but I've had reports on other devices as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to my question, and I think it's rather weird. The following bit of code does not work:

```
myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filePath), "video/*");
```

... but this does:

```
myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)), "video/*");
```

It would appear that `Uri.fromFile()` is required if you want the default OS video player to pop up in the list of applications capable of opening the video file. I have no idea why that's the case though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a real MIME type, for the actual type of the video, rather than one with a wildcard.

Comment: The Android documentation says that you can use `video/*`, and I have tried with others - same result.